# Fatal Error Adding Transaction Data to Data Layer on Woocommerce Thank You Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding data layer code to the header.php file to push transaction data to Google Analytics. When I add the code below to the header file, I get this error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on string in /home/site/public_html/XXX.com/wp-content/themes/nature/header.php:52

```
<!-- Transaction Data Layer -->
<?php if (is_order_received_page()): ?>
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$products = $order->get_items();
?>
<script>
  dataLayer.push({
      'ecommerce': {
        'currencyCode': 'US',
        'purchase': {
          'actionField':{
            'id': '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
            'affiliation': 'GEW',
            'revenue': <?php echo number_format($order->get_subtotal(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
            'tax': <?php echo number_format($order->get_total_tax(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
            'shipping': <?php echo number_format($order->calculate_shipping(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
            <?php if($order->get_used_coupons()): ?>
                'coupon': '<?php echo implode("-", $order->get_used_coupons()); ?>'
            <?php endif; ?>
          },
          'products': [
              <?php
                foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item):
                  $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
                  $variant_name = ($item['variation_id']) ? wc_get_product($item['variation_id']) : '';
              ?>
                  {
                    'name': '<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                    'id': '<?php echo $item['product_id']; ?>',
                    'price': '<?php echo number_format($order->get_line_subtotal($item), 2, ".", ""); ?>',
                    'brand': 'N',
                    'category': '<?php echo strip_tags($product->get_categories(', ', '', '')); ?>',
                    'variant': '<?php echo ($variant_name) ? implode("-", $variant_name->get_variation_attributes()) : ''; ?>',
                    'quantity': <?php echo $item['qty']; ?>
                  },
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: at a guess, the thank you page no longer has the transaction info as it's a separate page/call. you'll need to pass it. however, this seems highly unethical.

Comment: This is not related to your code, but to the plugin authnet-cim-for-woo…

Comment: I updated the code and error. I pasted the wrong error and code.